# Submultiplicity when dealing with fractions

Tags: functions, inequality

I understand that if $f: A \to B$ is a submultiplicative function, then $\exists K : f(ab)\leq K f(a)f(b)$ for every $(a,b)\in A\times A$. Now at some point, by arguing submultiplicity my teacher said that $f(\frac{a}{b})\leq K \frac{f(a)}{f(b)}$. For a function to behave like this is desirable, but to me, it should be $f(\frac{a}{b})\leq K f(a) f(\frac{1}{b})$. I don't know how get to my teacher's conclusion from my inequality, since I don't know (explicitly) if $f(\frac{1}{b})\leq \frac{1}{f(b)}$ or something similar. How should it be or what other properties should I assume for $f$ to be true?

Edit: There is an additional hypothesis and $f$ is increasing.

Comment: No it isn't, we are trying to obtain upper bounds.

Comment: Well I am getting a reverse inequality $f(a)=f(a/b\times b)\leq K f(a/b)f(b)$. After rearranging we get $f(a/b)\geq K^{-1}\frac{f(a)}{f(b)}.$